# Read local data into server.R

Tags: shiny

What are the steps to read a file on your local machine such as a CSV file into Shiny's server.R file so that it can be used by shinyServer() and ui.R, as opposed to loading a package? Please provide a code example.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways that you can do that but they are all similar. They will still use the read (e.g. `read.csv`) function.

1) You can create a global.R file and put all the global variables in there and then source the file using

```
 source("PATH TO YOUR FILE/Global.r", local = TRUE)
```

Look into the Tutorials on scoping [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#scoping)

2) You can place the read.csv() above the `shinyServer` in `server.R`

3) And you can import the .csv file in the App itself using `fileInput` example of which given [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/upload-file.html)